# Need a help in creating Macro for Difference formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am creating a Timesheet for tracking the working hours of employees. Below is the format of the Timesheet:

```
Date    Time in   Time out   Total hours       Break hour     Net hour
```

Total hours is difference between the Time out and Time in. Break hour will be filled manually, Net hour is the difference of Total hours and Break hour that is Total hours – Break hour. I want to create an excel worksheet, where I enter the Time in and Time out, the Total hours should be filled automatically and when I enter the Break hour, Net hour should be filled automatically.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

A macro is **not** needed.  With data like:

[image]

In **D2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(B2="",C2=""),"",C2-B2)
```

and copy down.  In **F2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(D2="",E2=""),"",D2-E2)
```

and copy down.

The results cells will appear empty until data is entered in the data cells.